# O que é "npm query"?

Tags: node.js, npm

Me deparei com um comando bem "estranho" em um terminal, usando o gerenciador de pacotes do Node.js `npm` (na versão `v8.19.2` do npm e `v18.12` do Node.js), porém com uma sintaxe diferente de do que eu estou acostumado:

```bash
npm query ":type(git)"
```

Resolvi fazer o teste e me retornou um array vazio (`[]`) no terminal (nem sei o que eu deveria esperar). Mas não parou por ai. Outro comando me chamou ainda mais atenção:

```bash
npm query "*"
```

O comando acima parece ser o equivalente do comando `npm list --all`, que lista todas as dependências de um projeto, porém, ele aparenta ser um pouco mais detalhado que o do `npm`.

- O que seria esse `npm query <comando aqui>`?
- Ele é um conjunto de comandos mais simplificados do `npm` como o do equivalente `npm list --all`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É um comando de alto nível que usa [Dependency Selector](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-query) para retornar um json com filtros de dependências do projeto. o **npm query** usa seletores css para conseguir um array de objetos de dependência. Acredito que a ideia é que tivéssemos uma familiaridade com forms de css, pela simplicidade da língua e os operadores utilizados para tornar as informações mais claras e bem acessíveis.

Se quisermos uma lista de todas as dependências de meu projeto:

`npm query "*"`

Se quisermos cada versão do React e lodash

```
npm query "#react, #lodash"
```

Se eu quisesse encontrar todas as versões do React não definidas como uma dependência de pares que posso executar:

```
npm query "#react:not(.peer)"
```

Como pode ver, a ideia é a praticidade de execução sobre a relação das dependências de seu projeto. Com o potencial para que os desenvolvedores se auto-atendam ao fazer novas e complexas perguntas sobre suas dependências, seus relacionamentos e metadados associativos.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).